# Wireshark packet details pane info with tshark or scapy?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, wireshark, scapy, tshark

The information I'd like to automate retrieval of via Bash or Python is what's contained in the Packet Details pane for the last layer, when viewing DIS protocol captured packets.

So far I've gotten to the point where I can read the Packet Bytes pane information with the Scapy library in Python, but this is much harder for me to interpret/work with.

```
from scapy.all import sniff
capture = sniff(filter="dst 10.6.255.255 and port 3000", count=5)
packet = capture[0]
print(packet.show())
raw = packet.lastlayer()

from scapy.utils import hexdump
hexdump(raw)
```

Is there any way that I can get the Packet Details pane information instead with Python or Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried things like:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -O dis
```

or even

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y dis -T pdml > file.pdml
```

Refer to the [tshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information on these options and to the [Wireshark PDML wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/PDML) for more information about the "Packet Description Markup Language".

Comment: Hi, thanks. the Packet Description Markup Language is probably what I'm looking for! Is there a way to further filter it so that it's just from the data layer?

Comment: I haven't really used PDML much, so I'm not that familiar with its capabilities.  I don't know if that's what the '-j' or '-J' options are for, but they appear to be broken to me, worthy of a bug report at https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/

Answer (score 0):

Hope I don’t get the question wrong :/

You have a pretty cool `packet.show()` function which looks somewhat similar to wireshark

[image]

You can also try pdf-dumping `packet.pdfdump()` (or svg-dumping with github version)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think what I actually need is something to decode DIS IEEE standard raw data, maybe like open-dis-python github repository.